# Setting up production/development environment in Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel-4

I was collaborating with a colleague of mine on GitHub, it's a project on Laravel. Now I made some commits and sent this guy the Git link, he had a good look and had the following to say:

> The migrations worked fine once I set the environment to development
>   instead of production. What I'll often do, and you certainly don't
>   have to, is set the default environment to development and set it to
>   production only if a variable has been set in the virtual host file or
>   in .htaccess.

Now I understood the part of setting up the default environment to development but what throws me totally off the hook is the word virtual host.

I read the documentation on Laravel about production environment, but what this person has said is a bit confusing to me. Can somebody clarify?

The same guy also sent me the below function :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {
        return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

I am new to Laravel, and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Environments

When your friend showed you the code:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('homestead'),
));
```

It is referring to the portion of the framework that allows you to tie a host name (`homestead`) to a particular environment name (`local`).

You can find the file that has this code in your project at `bootstrap/start.php`. or look at it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v4.2.11/bootstrap/start.php).

When you give an environment name to a particular hostname the framework will load configuration settings differently. If you look at the folder:

```
app/config/
```

You'll notice that there is a folder named `local`. That folder contains some configuration files that match those in the root of your `app/config/` folder. When you launch the framework on a computer that has the host name that you specified in the start.php file, it uses any settings you give in the `local/` version of the files before applying the regular config version.

This means if you use different database credentials for your local environment you can put those in the `config/local/database.php` config and they will only be used when launching the framework in your local environment.

The config items in your `local` directory cascade so you only need to add the configurations that are different from your production environment.

You can set up different environments by adding a new environment name and the hostname of the computer that it should run on:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local'   => array('homestead'),
    'testing' => array('testserver')
));
```

Now I can create a folder called `app/config/testing`, add in a new `database.php` config file and specific the credentials for my testing database. When the framework is launched from the testing server any details from the `testing` config files will be used and then the remaining config details will come from the default (production) environment config files.

Also, Laravel 4.2 assumes `app/config` as your production environment, so when you launch the framework on your production server it will use all of the credentials in the config files at `app/config`

You can read more on [how Laravel handles configurations here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration).

## The Virtual Machine (Homestead)

The virtual machine your friend was talking about, [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead), is the official virtual development environment for Laravel. It's basically a virtual machine that is tuned specifically for working with laravel (though you can use it for non-Laravel projects too). Laracasts has a [fee video talking about homestead](https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two) that will help fill you in.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the elaborate answer , i'll go through it and accept it .

Comment: No problem :) I hope it helps

Comment: I should note that this answer is specifically for laravel 4. The environment specific configuration has changed in L5.